# Copy Next last row cell and Paste into Same Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to create a function with copies the next cell and paste data into same cell but i really do not know how to create it.

Any help will be much appreciated.

```
Dim Lrow As Long
With Sheet1
Lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
.Range("C2:C" & Lrow).Copy Sheet7.Range("A2")
.Range("I2:I" & Lrow).Copy Sheet7.Range("C2")
.Range("B2:B" & Lrow).Copy Sheet7.Range("D2")
.Range("G2:G" & Lrow).Copy Sheet7.Range("E2")
.Range("S2:S" & Lrow).Copy Sheet7.Range("F2")
.Range("D2:D" & Lrow).Copy Sheet7.Range("H2")
.Range("E2:E" & Lrow).Copy Sheet7.Range("I2")
.Range("L2:L" & Lrow).Copy Sheet7.Range("J2")
.Range("N2:N" & Lrow).Copy Sheet7.Range("K2")
.Range("Q2:Q" & Lrow).Copy Sheet7.Range("L2")
.Range("R2:R" & Lrow).Copy Sheet7.Range("M2")
.Range("M2:M" & Lrow).Copy Sheet7.Range("N2")
End Wit
```

Comment: Your codes should work. What problem you are facing with these codes?

Comment: My function paste the last cell into new row instead of row 2. And it copies the all cells not last cell

Comment: So, you want only last cell to copy?

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: Please try my answer.

Comment: Do you need copying only **one cell (the last one of the column)**?

Comment: Yes i need to copy the last cell. If there is not data under headers then paste as empty.

Comment: Are there all the columns to be processed equal in terms of rows? I mean, do they have the same number of rows?

Comment: Yes they should have the same number of rows like cell A16, C16, E16 and so on

Comment: Then you should insert a new code line after `Lrow` calculation: `If Lrow < 2 Then Exit Sub`... But use `.Range("C" & Lrow).Copy Sheet7.Range("A2")` and so on, not like you try...

Comment: Thank you very much  @FaneDuru. I was blank that i could not think about the IF condition thank you for letting me know.

Comment: No @FaneDuru its not working as i expected because i am calling this function by `WorkSheet_change` event i do not know why it does not respond when it is being called first time. After making second attempt it copies and paste the values.

Comment: Please, explain what "its not working as i expected" does mean. Theoretically, the code must work being called from an event to. If it should modify something in the same sheet, you should use `Application.EnableEvents = false` before the modification and ``Application.EnableEvents = true` , but copying an another sheet, it should not care about it. If not something confidential, can you share the workbook in discussion?

Comment: Yes i have tried with `Application.EnableEvents = false` but its still not working. If you will not bother i can send you the file personally with the details because file has all data of the company profile.

Comment: Yes, you can send it, but it is good to announce me. Otherwise, it will enter in Spam folder...

Comment: Before sending, you must take care of some issues? Would you like the event to be triggered by **any change**? Isn't it better to be triggered only by changings in the range where the data needs to be copied? Do that changes are done by copying of all the row? If not and manually modified, shouldn't it be better to copy **only the modified cell value**?

Comment: Yes I followed the advice as you stated but there must be an issue with file which does not consider the first initiation of code. I will let you know before sharing the file. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a try to below codes.

```
Sub MyCopy()
Dim Lrow As Long
    With Sheet1
    Lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    If Lrow <= 2 Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        .Range("C" & Lrow).Copy Sheet7.Range("A2")
        .Range("I" & Lrow).Copy Sheet7.Range("C2")
        .Range("B" & Lrow).Copy Sheet7.Range("D2")
        .Range("G" & Lrow).Copy Sheet7.Range("E2")
        .Range("S" & Lrow).Copy Sheet7.Range("F2")
        .Range("D" & Lrow).Copy Sheet7.Range("H2")
        .Range("E" & Lrow).Copy Sheet7.Range("I2")
        .Range("L" & Lrow).Copy Sheet7.Range("J2")
        .Range("N" & Lrow).Copy Sheet7.Range("K2")
        .Range("Q" & Lrow).Copy Sheet7.Range("L2")
        .Range("R" & Lrow).Copy Sheet7.Range("M2")
        .Range("M" & Lrow).Copy Sheet7.Range("N2")
    End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried this but it copies the first row (which are headers) if there is no value in row 2. Is there a way to skip the row 1

Comment: Yes that is expected behavior. If there is no data under headers then headers are last data in a column.

Comment: Yes but i need to skip idf there is no data under headers

Comment: That is for all columns or specific columns? Suppose you have data in `C` column under header but there is no data to other columns under header. Then you want last cell of `C` column and other columns will copy nothing? Or if there will no data under header for all columns?

Comment: Exactly if there is no data in other column but Column C has then copy last cell and paste. If there is no data under all column returns as empty. If there is data in single column other do not have then copy last cell of single column.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236040/discussion-between-harun24hr-and-valiant).

Comment: No its not working because code is initiated twice then it works.